# メイン・メタの新デザイン適用

Tags: サポート, デザイン

去年の１１月より[英語版のStack Overflow Metaでは新デザインを適用しました](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/277200/feedback-requested-stack-overflow-design-update)。

今日から同じデザインを日本語版（メインサイトもメタも）に適用しました。

レティナディスプレイのサポートを強化しましたし、将来のCSSやロゴのメンテナンスもやりやすくしました。全体的にスペーシングとレイアウトを統一しました。

新デザインに関わるバグを探したら、[バグ](/questions/tagged/%e3%83%90%e3%82%b0)と[デザイン](/questions/tagged/%e3%83%87%e3%82%b6%e3%82%a4%e3%83%b3)で[投稿してください](https://ja.meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/ask?title=%E6%96%B0%E3%83%87%E3%82%B6%E3%82%A4%E3%83%B3%EF%BC%9A%20&tags=%E3%83%90%E3%82%B0+%E3%83%87%E3%82%B6%E3%82%A4%E3%83%B3)

Comment: [英語版のメインにも、1月16日に反映済み](http://meta.stackoverflow.com/q/283614/20226)です。